# How to determine the way of method calling from child class

Tags: php, class, scope

Please help me. 
For example I have a class Foo which extends from class Bar.

```
    class Bar
    {
          public function __call($func, $args){
               echo "Calling method {$func}";
          }
          public function __callstatic($func, $args){
               echo "Calling static method {$func}";
          }
          public function run(){
               echo "calling Bar::run method \n";
          }
    }
    class Foo extends Bar
    {
          public $objBar;
          public function __construct(){
              $this -> objBar = new Bar();
          }
          public function callViaObject(){
              $this -> objBar -> run();
              $this -> objBar -> run1();
          }
          public function callViaParent(){
              parent::run();
              parent::run1();
          }
    }
    $foo = new foo();
    $foo -> callViaObject(); 
    /* output 
       calling Bar::run method \n
       Calling method run1; */
    $foo -> callViaParent();
    /* output 
       calling Bar::run method \n
       Calling method run1; !! */
```

Here's a problem, when I call method with `parent::` from child class, and the parent class has an object, the call method `parent::` is not static call.

So how can I check in `Bar` class, how called the method ? 
Can I check the call type is parent:: ?

Thank You all very much !!

Comment: Have you tried changing `__callstatic` into `__callStatic` (notice the capital S)? That could be the cause.

Comment: I tried but its the same.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `private static function run1() {}` in Your class A.

Comment: Thank You! But @diplex19 already helped me. [link]https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53826